# How are the images at AllRGB.com created?

Tags: software-recommendation, rgb

The images at AllRGB.com have all 65536 (on 16-bit color depth) or all 16777216 (24-bit color depth images) colors in one image, not one redundant color and not one missing one.

Each pixel has it's unique color, and the number of unique colors equals bit depth and equals the number of pixels in that image.

How exactly are these images created?

Comment: I stumbled upon [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/images-with-all-colors) on SE Programming Puzzles & Code Golf where you can see many different approaches.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor Do we have to use american english here?

Answer (score 2):

It's performed by running an image through a script.

This script by Fogelman is a good place to start: [Scripts for creating AllRGB](https://github.com/fogleman/AllRGB)

---

How it works is by using an octree, to spatially represent the RGB colors. The octree is only 9 levels deep from root to leaf (inclusive). Each node in the octree stores a count for how many colors in its subtree are still available to be used. The octree is stored in a flat array, as it is a complete octree. Children indexes are computed as:

```
8 * i + 1 + x
```

...where i is the current index and x specifies the xth (0 - 7) child. To find a color in the octree, use a single bit from each of R, G and B to form a 3-bit number representing the next child node to visit. Repeat this process from the most significant to the least significant bits.

For example, if RGB = (27, 89, 233)...

```
   12345678
R: 00011011
G: 01011001
B: 11101001
```

001, 011, 001, 110, 111, 000, 100, 111 => 1, 3, 1, 6, 7, 0, 4, 7
When encountering a node with a value of zero (meaning no colors are available in that space), visit a different child instead to find as similar of a color as possible. But don't just pick a random other child, pick one that will minimize error, especially in the green channel. A lookup table is used for this purpose.

```
LOOKUP = [
    [0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7],
    [1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6],
    [2, 3, 6, 7, 0, 1, 4, 5],
    [3, 2, 7, 6, 1, 0, 5, 4],
    [4, 5, 0, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3],
    [5, 4, 1, 0, 7, 6, 3, 2],
    [6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1],
    [7, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0],
]
```

Optionally, if some areas of the image are more important than others, such as a face, let those pixels pick their colors first - give them priority. This was not done in the sample image. The pixels in the sample were simply ordered randomly.

---

Alternatively, results can be achieved through [Processing.org Software](https://processing.org/)